# DBS 10 Speed Conversion - Bottom bracket?

Tags: bottom-bracket, fixed-gear

I have dismantled and thrown away the old parts of this DBS 10 Speed bike I'm converting to a fixed-gear. Yesterday I received a [48T Espresso crankset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4sMC.jpg), but now I wonder which bottom bracket to get. The shell width is 68mm. Can anyone help me to get the right size for a bottom bracket?

#### The bike as I found it originally

[image: DBS 10 Speed]

#### The bike after I have stripped it down

[image: DBS 10 Speed]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be one of those bikes with a weird scandanavian bottom bracket, called a fauber bottom bracket.  Not even sheldon mentions this style on his site.

You may need to get an adapter to adapt this to fit english thread bottom brackets
http://fixedgearbikes.blogspot.com/2010/04/fauber-bottom-bracket-adapter.html

The link will send you to a finnish website, so you may need to call (the owner speaks english) to place an order.

After putting in the adapter, you should be able to use any standard english bottom bracket. Just want to make sure you get the right spindle length on the new BB.  107mm should probably work if you're running the chainring on the outer facing side of the crank spider, 110mm if you're bolting the chainring to the inside of the crank spider. Probably wouldn't be bad if you got a longer spindle than you needed though.  Your crank may come with specs for a preferred spindle length.

See [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_bracket) about bottom brackets for more details.

Here is another link to fish for info:
http://www.bikeforums.net/showthread.php/372038-Swedish-Norwegian-Bottom-Brackets-One-piece-cranks

Comment: Great answer! Though I doubt it would fit snugly, Velo-Orange makes an expanding bottom bracket which works in ISO/French/Swiss/Raleigh...shells regardless of threading (http://store.velo-orange.com/index.php/components/bottom-brackets/grand-cru-threadless-bottom-brackets.html). Since those shells are between 33mm-34mm ID it is a good option, but the Fauber shell diameter is 45mm and I doubt that the VO design expands enough to compensate for that 10mm.

Comment: Additionally, Phil Wood makes a number of odd style BB cups to fit their cartridges (http://www.philwood.com/products/bbpages/bbcups.php). Unfortunately, they don't make Fauber-compatible cups.

Comment: @WTHarper - VO BB doesn't work with italian threading since it's got a larger inside diameter they claim.  Since Fauber has an even larger inside diameter than italian, I doubt the VO BB would work.

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at my bike later today and see if I need the fauber bottom bracket adapter. Also thanks for good resource links.